# Combine two SQL queries or prevent exclusion of data rows in existing query

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I have a SQL query:

```
SELECT 
    AnalyticsHub_Requests.Id AS reqId, AnalyticsHub_Requests.*,
    AnalyticsHub_StatusCodes.ShortDescription AS StatusText,
    Users.FullName + ' (' + COALESCE(WorkPhone,'Phone empty') + ')' AS Value, 
    Users.Id 
FROM 
    AnalyticsHub_StatusCodes 
INNER JOIN 
    (Users 
INNER JOIN 
    AnalyticsHub_Requests ON Users.[Id] = AnalyticsHub_Requests.[AssigneeId]) ON AnalyticsHub_StatusCodes.[Id] = AnalyticsHub_Requests.[StatusId]
WHERE  
    AnalyticsHub_Requests.StatusId = 4 
    OR AnalyticsHub_Requests.StatusId = 6;
```

This returns 3 rows of data when all issues have an assignee. If an issue doesn't have an assignee, however, it will omit from the results. I've tried several different approaches but to no avail. How can I include data rows without an assignee in my results?

Comment: Have you tried an OUTER JOIN?

Comment: What is an "assignee"? Am I just not seeing that table? Try an `outer join`.

Comment: I will be honest, I am new to this and don't have a good grasp as to how that works. I used the designer mode in Access to generate this query for my site.

Comment: I believe you should change your second inner join to RIGHT OUTER JOIN

Comment: @Steve This is a private ticketing system. It has data fields describing an incedent in the AnalyticsHub_Requests table and pairs that information up with a name from the Users table.

Comment: Then you need a right join `Users RIGHT JOIN AnalyticsHub_Requests `

Comment: Using the RIGHT JOIN and RIGHT OUTER JOIN I was able to display the right information. If you submit this as an answer I would be glad to accept it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using the RIGHT JOIN (as mentioned in comments) I was able to prevent my query from omitting results.

```
SELECT 
AnalyticsHub_Requests.Id AS reqId, AnalyticsHub_Requests.*,
AnalyticsHub_StatusCodes.ShortDescription AS StatusText,
Users.FullName + ' (' + COALESCE(WorkPhone,'Phone empty') + ')' AS Value, 
Users.Id 
FROM 
AnalyticsHub_StatusCodes 
INNER JOIN 
(Users 
RIGHT JOIN 
AnalyticsHub_Requests ON Users.[Id] = AnalyticsHub_Requests.[AssigneeId])     
ON AnalyticsHub_StatusCodes.[Id] = AnalyticsHub_Requests.[StatusId]
WHERE  
AnalyticsHub_Requests.StatusId = 4 
OR AnalyticsHub_Requests.StatusId = 6;
```